# How does the windows run dialog locate executables?

Tags: windows, run-dialog

When I enter "firefox" in the windows run dialog (i.e. the dialog that appears when you hit <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), firefox will launch.

However, "firefox.exe" is not in my `%path%` because when I type "firefox" in `cmd.exe`, I get

> 'firefox' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

So apparently an executable doesn't need to be found in the windows `%path%` in order to be discoverable by the run dialog. How does this work?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Apparently the run dialog checks not only the %path% environment variable, but also the **"App Path" registry key**. From [a techrepublic article about the run dialog](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5034562.html):

> You can launch some third-party
>   applications by typing the name of the
>   executable file in the Open text box
>   and clicking OK—even though the paths
>   to these applications don’t appear in
>   the path environment variable. The
>   reason that this is possible is
>   because the installation procedure for
>   some applications adds the executable
>   file's path to a special registry key
>   called App Paths.

The relevant locations in the registry are `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` (this last one being specific to the user). You can add your own "app paths" there with regedit.

Comment: Thank you, I was baffled by the same thing (firefox) and your answer explained it well.

Comment: Also, don't forget to check `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`. I was encounter this problem as well because I installed Beta + Canary versions of Chrome but couldn't understand why Canary was opening but not the stable version of chrome, despite both not being in the `%PATH%`. Turns out this answer helped, but it was under `HKCU` instead of `HKLM`!

Answer (score 2):

The Run dialog on newer versions of Windows will also run shortcuts found in your start menu. I'm not sure when this started working... it may go back as far as Windows 95, though I do not think so.

Edit: This answer is wrong. The correct answer is the App Paths registry key, as answered above.

Comment: I believe it was XP, but not certain.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the correct explanation. I can find counter examples of applications in my start menu (such as TrueCrypt) which I can't start via the run dialog.

Comment: The Run dialog remains unchanged even in recent versions of Windows. The search box in the Start Menu is another matter, though. But that's more a search box that also happens to run programs found in the PATH.

Comment: If this is wrong, then you should have deleted it. Though, honestly, that seems like expected behavior to me.