# Why is "run" a usable command in Windows 8.1's Run dialogue?

Tags: windows-8.1, run-dialog

Using Windows 8.1 Professional edition I'm able to use `run` as a command within the Windows Run Dialogue (accessed using <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>:

[image: Run Dialogue Example]

In the regular Windows 8.1 edition (not Professional), typing `run` here will produce an error about how it isn't recognised as a command, but in Windows 8.1 Professional this causes the Run dialogue to close and nothing more to happen.

However we can then take this a step further: Typing `run calc` opens the Calculator application (just as typing `calc` by itself would):

[image: Run Calc Example]

Voilà:

[image: Result]

We can then take this even further by chaining the `run` command. `run run calc` also opens the calculator, as does `run run run run run run run run run calc`, etc.

[image: Run Run Calc Example]

What is the purpose of allowing `run` to be executed in Windows' Run dialogue, and why is it possible to chain it? Equally, why is this not available in the regular Windows 8.1 edition?

Comment: `Run` is not a regular Windows command line command. I don't have a Windows 8.1 Pro machine handy to test on right now, but have you confirm this on other Win 8.1 machines?  Your specific machine may have a `run` batch file or alike someplace in the path.  Where is the `run` file actually located in the file system on your machine?

Comment: It is possible on `Windows 8.1 Core` ( there isn't a "home edition" of Windows 8.1 or Windows 8.  As for the reason it wasn't working in your tests, that's because of a PATH problem more then likely, because in my testing I had no problems running calc.exe from the run prompt.  Which by the way only requires you to type in "calc".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the windows run dialog locate executables?](http://superuser.com/questions/87372/how-does-the-windows-run-dialog-locate-executables)

Comment: @Ramhound The user is pointing out that on Win 8.1 Pro he can run a program, via the Run dialog, named "Run" which seems to be a launcher of some kind(?).  Are you saying there is a valid "Run" program on Windows 8.1 (Pro and Core)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - No;  I am not.  I am saying I was able to use the run prompt to start calc.exe on a `Windows 8.1 Core` installation within a virtual box.  As for `run` being a standard command line command I will have to get back with you on that.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 Pro, and I am not able to use "run" in the run dialog. If I try to do "run calc", I get "Windows cannot find 'run'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.".  I would guess that there is a "run.exe" or "run.bat" or somesuch, somewhere in the PATH of James Donnelly's 8.1 Pro machine, or in either the user or machine registry hives under SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have cygwin installed on the Windows 8.1 Pro machine? Cygwin has a run.exe command included that will make the "run calc" command string work. It doesn't work on a Windows 8.1 machine without a third party software package that provides a "run" command, this is why it fails on most other machines.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer. Unfortunately I've no longer got access to the machine which had `run` as an available command.